# Load a template with Django and React JS with a single GET call

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am building an application with Django as the backend and React js for making the interface of the application.

I have a set of Posts which I want to display.

Currently, the approach which I am following is -

1. Get the template having the compiled js code linked to it.
2. Then again make get call to get the posts

My question is - In this current approach I am making **2 GET** calls to the backend, one for rendering the template and then again for getting the Post.

What is the best way to achieve this? Is this the usual flow how applications are built using Django and React JS?

Comment: The point of using a JS framework like React is that you make one request to get the JS for *all* the pages, then individual requests to get the relevant data for the pages you are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: I don't see anything wrong with doing this in two requests, because one loads the application itself and the second loads the content. To me this seperation makes sense and might turn out to be useful in the future if you want to reuse say the Endpoint, that yields the the posts(i.e. the content).

Answering your question: If, for whatever reason, you absolutely want to load everything with a single GET, a good way of doing so, would be to pass a list of posts to the context as a JSON-serialized object and then load these into the JS-context within the Django-template.

i.e. in the view.py:

```
from json import dumps

def view(request):
    context = {
        'posts':get_posts(),
    }
    render_to_response('django_template.html', context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
def get_posts():
    qs = Posts.objects.all()
    return dumps({'posts': qs })
```

in the django_template:

```
    {% block content %}
    <div id="root"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        var INITIAL_POSTS = {{ posts|safe }};
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="PATH_TO_STATIC_REACT_ASSET.JS"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

you should now have your posts in your JS context and can load them in your React component. Once again: I would agree with Daniel Rosemans comment

Comment: thanks for the response, yes indeed it can be reused, I think this approach will be cumbersome for me to maintain, as I'll have to remember to include the initial context data every time, I think if making 2 get calls doesn't have a big impact then going with that approach will be good for now. Thanks

Comment: I agree. If you're using your own API to provide the data I would consider passing the urls from the Django context/ template( using something along the lines of `var ENPOINT_1 = {%url "api:name_of_endpoint"}` though. It will make your application much more robust to changes in the url scheme. Please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your problem ;-)

Comment: thanks for your response, i'll look for a better solution, otherwise I'll accept it.

Comment: @ShahrukhMohammad Alright. We seem to have different understandings of what a useful answer is.